# Databinding a nested List property in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am using the following XAML code to display a list of checked list boxes.

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbxProjects" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <ListBox x:Name="lbxUnits" ItemsSource="{Binding Units}">
                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <CheckBox Content="{Binding unit.Name}" IsChecked="{Binding isSelected}"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

The data model is as follows

```
public class ProjectsListBox 
    {
        public Project project { get; set; }
        public List<UnitsCheckBox> Units = new List<UnitsCheckBox>();
        public ProjectsListBox(Project project)
        {
            this.project = project;           
            foreach(var d in project.Documents)
            {
                Units.Add(new UnitsCheckBox(d));
            }
        }        
    }

    public class UnitsCheckBox : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public Document unit { get; set; }
        private bool isselected = true;
        public bool isSelected
        {
            get { return isselected; }
            set
            {
                isselected = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("isSelected");                
            }
        }
        public UnitsCheckBox(Document d)
        {
            unit = d;
        }
}
```

I am assigning the data source for the parent listbox like

```
lbxProjects.DataContext = projectsList;
```

The code creates the child list boxes but not the checkboxes inside the child list boxes. What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

How should WPF resolve unit.Name?

If the type UnitsCheckBox contains a Name property, then the CheckBox's Content should be bound to Name:

```
Content="{Binding Name}"
```

You should always specify the type of your DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:UnitsCheckBox}" ...>
```

Those are the probable problems but I can't be sure unless you give us the UnitsCheckBox code.